# SIMCOM SIM7080G certificate conversion error on AT+CSSLCFG command

Tags: ssl-certificate, at-command, modem, nb-iot

I am using sim7080g https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM7080G_Cat-M/NB-IoT_HAT , I am experiencing this certificate conversion issue.

AT commands I am passing are as follows:

```
AT
AT+CMNB=2
AT+CNMP=38
AT+CBANDCFG=NB-IOT
AT+CPIN?
AT+CEREG?
AT+CGATT?
AT+CSQ?
AT+CNCFG=0,0
AT+CNACT=0,1


AT+CFSINIT
AT+CFSWFILE=3,"ca.crt",0,1188,10000
AT+CSSLCFG="CONVERT",2,"ca.crt"
```

everything returns OK, except the last AT command, it throws an operation not allowed CME error.

```
AT+CSSLCFG=convert,2,ca.crt
+CME ERROR: operation not allowed
```

Does anyone know a solution?